# Why is the text behaving like this?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text

Look at this, it is impossible to get the text to behave normally now.
I want the text to be two separate lines.
I press enter to get it to change line.

I guess I could make two different texts but this should work without a problem...

Photoshop CC on Mac Os X Sierra.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your leading in the character panel. - for more information see the Adobe help: https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/line-character-spacing.html

Answer (score 1):

See image:[image]
Go to Windows drop down menu and then character, then Set Leading Icon.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be your baseline shift. Set your baseline shift to 0 after highlighting the both lines.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to set the leading.

Step 1 is are the lines without the spacing.

Step 2: Click on the text >> Ctr A (the entire text will be selected). Then Ctr T. A panel will open. Then set the spacing according to your requirement. If you set it on auto it will set the spacing proportionately.

Check this:
[image]